# NodeJS ExpressJS. Multer returns undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer

## **I followed the steps from the multer documentation but still it's still showing undefined**

---

### post.js

I've tried both diskStorage() and memoryStorage(), none of it worked.

```
app.get("/adminposts", function(req, res, next){
    // FILE LOC: routes/Admin/database
    res.render('Admin/post', {
        title : '*** Admin Posts'
    })
})

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'uploads')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
  })

// var storage = multer({storage:multer.memoryStorage()}) //still undefined
var upload = multer({storage: storage})
app.post('/adminposts/upload', upload.single('image_post'), (req, res)=>{
  //some req.body
  var image = req.file

  console.log(image) // undefined
```

---

### post.ejs

I'm not sure what I have done wrong on this part. I just couldn't understand. Though when I console.log the image id it shows 'fakePath:------'

```
        //other inputs here
        <input type="file" name="image_post" accept=".jpg,.gif,.png" id="image">
    </form> 

<script>   
    $.ajax({
    url:"http://localhost:3000/adminposts/upload",
    method:"POST",
    data:$('#upload_post').serialize(),
    dataType:"JSON",
    success:function(data)
    {
        //some success here
```

Comment: Could you add some more details like for example what is where undefined?

Comment: Hello @tung! Sorry for the late reply. After the day of this post, I tried the actual documentation from the website. I discovered that I don't need ajax to perform multer.